# Why is this test FFT program giving incorrect results?

Tags: fortran, fft, fortran77

I am writing a Fortran code which requires an FFT. I am using the double precision version of four1 from Numerical Recipes in Fortran 77 (page 501). Below is a program to test the FFT. Below that is the output I get from the FFT along with the output I expect to get. The real part of the transform is correct within rounding errors, but the imaginary part is not. However, for my purposes, I do not even need the imaginary part, so should I be able to just grab the real part and continue with that? It still bothers me that the output is not correct though and makes me think I don't understand something about the implimentation of this subroutine.

The way I understand it, the values given to the array "data" when it is constructed are all real (1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0). And the imaginary values are all zero. Is that correct? I am concerned that I am not giving the input array to the FFT in the form that it needs. When I use this subroutine in my actual program, what comes out of the FFT is somewhat nonsensical and the whole thing goes to NaNs after several timesteps.

```
program fftTest
    implicit none   
    complex(kind=8), dimension(8) :: data = (/1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0/)
    integer :: i

    do i=1,8
        write(*,'("(", F20.15, ",", F20.15, "i )")') data(i)
    end do
print *, '-----'

call dfour1(data,8,1)

    do i=1,8
        write(*,'("(", F20.15, ",", F20.15, "i )")') data(i)
    end do
print *, '-----'

call dfour1(data,8,-1)
data = data/8

do i=1,8
        write(*,'("(", F20.15, ",", F20.15, "i )")') data(i)
    end do

end program fftTest

    SUBROUTINE dfour1(data,nn,isign)
        INTEGER isign,nn
        DOUBLE PRECISION data(2*nn)
        INTEGER i,istep,j,m,mmax,n
        DOUBLE PRECISION tempi,tempr
        DOUBLE PRECISION theta,wi,wpi,wpr,wr,wtemp 
        n=2*nn
        j=1
        do 11 i=1,n,2 !This is the bit reversal section of the routine.
            if(j.gt.i)then
            tempr=data(j) !Exchange the two complex numbers.
            tempi=data(j+1)
            data(j)=data(i)
            data(j+1)=data(i+1)
            data(i)=tempr
            data(i+1)=tempi
        endif
        m=n/2
1       if ((m.ge.2).and.(j.gt.m)) then
            j=j-m
            m=m/2
        goto 1
        endif
        j=j+m
11    continue
      mmax=2 !Here begins the Danielson-Lanczos section of the routine.
2     if (n.gt.mmax) then                   
          istep=2*mmax
          theta=6.28318530717959d0/(isign*mmax)
          wpr=-2.d0*sin(0.5d0*theta)**2
          wpi=sin(theta)
          wr=1.d0
          wi=0.d0
          do 13 m=1,mmax,2  !Here are the two nested inner loops.
              do 12 i=m,n,istep
                 j=i+mmax   !This is the Danielson-Lanczos formula:
                 tempr=wr*data(j)-wi*data(j+1)
                 tempi=wr*data(j+1)+wi*data(j)
                 data(j)=data(i)-tempr
                 data(j+1)=data(i+1)-tempi
                 data(i)=data(i)+tempr
                 data(i+1)=data(i+1)+tempi
12        continue
          wtemp=wr  !Trigonometric recurrence
          wr=wr*wpr-wi*wpi+wr
          wi=wi*wpr+wtemp*wpi+wi
13      continue
        mmax=istep
        goto 2  !Not yet done.
        endif   !All done.
        return 
    END
```

Expected (correct) output:
    (   4.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   1.000000000000000,  -2.414213562373095i )
    (   0.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   1.000000000000000,  -0.414213562373095i )
    (   0.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   1.000000000000000,   0.414213562373095i )
    (   0.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   1.000000000000000,   2.414213562373095i )

Actual output from test program:
    (   1.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   1.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   1.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   1.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   0.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   0.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   0.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   0.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
     -----
    (   4.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   0.999999999999998,   2.414213562373094i )
    (   0.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   0.999999999999999,   0.414213562373096i )
    (   0.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   1.000000000000000,  -0.414213562373094i )
    (   0.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   1.000000000000003,  -2.414213562373096i )
     -----
    (   1.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   1.000000000000000,  -0.000000000000000i )
    (   1.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   1.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   0.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   0.000000000000000,   0.000000000000000i )
    (   0.000000000000000,  -0.000000000000000i )
    (   0.000000000000000,  -0.000000000000000i )

Comment: Obligatory [Boycott Numerical Recipes](http://www.astro.umd.edu/~bjw/software/boycottnr.html) link and suggestion to use the free [FFTW library](http://www.fftw.org/) which is faster than the ancient NR routine you are implementing.

Comment: You are passing a complex array to a double precision array. If you put your subroutine into a module and `use` that module, the compiler will tell you this.  You can do this even with the fixed-form source layout of FORTRAN 77. Also, specific kind values (e.g., 8) are not portable.  If you want to declare variables by their lengths, I suggest using the named types from the iso_fortran_env module.

Comment: @KyleKanos FFTW is not always easy to use, particularly on Windows

Comment: The FFTW FAQ says not to ask  Windows-specific questions.   Another option with an Open Source license is the GNU Scientific Library (GSL).  FGSL (http://www.lrz.de/services/software/mathematik/gsl/fortran/) provides a Fortran interface via Fortran's ISO C Binding -- example in my answer.

Comment: @KyleKanos: calm down, I was just contributing to the discussion, no animosity on my part

Comment: Another reason not to use GSL would be its license. Not everyone is at liberty to distribute his/her code under GPL... For FFTs I use [Kiss FFT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/) which has a BSD license. It's a C library, though, so one has to use `ISO_C_BINDING`.

Comment: @bdforbes: no hate here, just trying to point out that *your* experience is not *everyone's* experience. There are free alternatives to NR that should not be overlooked was the point of my original comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
program fftTest
    use iso_fortran_env
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: nn = 8
    real(real64), dimension(2*nn) :: data = [ 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,   &
         0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]
    integer :: i

    do i=1,2*nn,2
        write(*,'("(", F20.15, ",", F20.15, "i )")') data(i),data(i+1)
    end do
print *, '-----'

call dfour1(data,nn,-1)

    do i=1,2*nn,2
        write(*,'("(", F20.15, ",", F20.15, "i )")') data(i),data(i+1)
    end do
print *, '-----'

call dfour1(data,nn,+1)
data = data/8

do i=1,2*nn,2
        write(*,'("(", F20.15, ",", F20.15, "i )")') data(i),data(i+1)
    end do

end program fftTest
```

and a demo of using the GNU Scientific Library, which is Open Source, via Forran's ISO C Binding:

```
program fftTest
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    integer (c_size_t), parameter :: nn = 8
    real(C_DOUBLE), dimension(2*nn) :: data = [ 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,   &
         0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]
    integer :: i
    integer :: result

    interface
    !  Adapted from Fortran GSL Library, FGSL,
    !  http://www.lrz.de/services/software/mathematik/gsl/fortran/
      function gsl_fft_complex_radix2_backward(data, stride, n) bind(c)
         import :: c_size_t, c_double, c_int
         integer(c_size_t), value :: stride, n
         real (c_double), dimension(*), intent (inout)  :: data
         integer(c_int) :: gsl_fft_complex_radix2_backward
      end function gsl_fft_complex_radix2_backward
      function gsl_fft_complex_radix2_forward(data, stride, n) bind(c)
         import :: c_size_t, c_double, c_int
         integer(c_size_t), value :: stride, n
         real (c_double), dimension(*), intent (inout)  :: data
         integer(c_int) :: gsl_fft_complex_radix2_forward
      end function gsl_fft_complex_radix2_forward
    end interface

    do i=1,2*nn,2
        write(*,'("(", F20.15, ",", F20.15, "i )")') data(i),data(i+1)
    end do
   print *, '-----'

   result = gsl_fft_complex_radix2_forward (data, 1_c_size_t, nn)
   write (*, '("GSL return code: ", I0)' )  result

    do i=1,2*nn,2
        write(*,'("(", F20.15, ",", F20.15, "i )")') data(i),data(i+1)
    end do
   print *, '-----'

   result = gsl_fft_complex_radix2_backward (data, 1_c_size_t, nn)
   write (*, '("GSL return code: ", I0)' )  result
   data = data/8

   do i=1,2*nn,2
      write(*,'("(", F20.15, ",", F20.15, "i )")') data(i),data(i+1)
   end do

end program fftTest
```